# cabal new-build on a library; how to run tests?

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, cabal-new

**I've upgraded to cabal-install 1.24.** I'm trying to follow [this blog post](http://blog.ezyang.com/2016/05/announcing-cabal-new-build-nix-style-local-builds/) to build and test my library. I've done this

```
cabal new-configure --enable-tests --ghc-options=-Werror
cabal new-build
```

Here's the output from the cabal `new-build...` command. **Note that it never actually says that it's building my library `creatur`.**

```
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
primitive-0.6.1.0
regex-base-0.93.2
regex-posix-0.95.2
tf-random-0.5
QuickCheck-2.8.2
xml-1.3.14
test-framework-0.8.1.1
test-framework-hunit-0.3.0.2
test-framework-quickcheck2-0.3.0.3
creatur-5.9.11
Configuring primitive-0.6.1.0...
Configuring regex-base-0.93.2...
Configuring xml-1.3.14...
Building xml-1.3.14...
Building regex-base-0.93.2...
Building primitive-0.6.1.0...
```

And the installation doesn't show up in `cabal info`.

```
$ cabal info creatur
* creatur          (library)
    Synopsis:      Framework for artificial life experiments.
    Versions available: 4.2.0, 4.3.2, 4.3.3, 5.7.3, 5.8.0, 5.8.2, 5.9.9, 5.9.10,
                        5.9.11 (and 51 others)
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ]
. . .
```

And if I understand the blog post correctly, I should be able to run the test by executing

```
./dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/TEST/TEST
```

**But I don't see any executables in `dist-newstyle`.** What am I doing wrong?

```
$ find ./dist-newstyle/ -executable -type f
./dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/libHScreatur-5.9.11-inplace-ghc7.10.3.so
```

---

Here's my `cabal.project.local`:

```
tests: True

program-options
  ghc-options: -Werror
```

Here's my cabal file (`creatur.cabal`):

```
Name:              creatur
Version:           5.9.11
Stability:         experimental
Synopsis:          Framework for artificial life experiments.
Description:       A software framework for automating experiments
                   with artificial life. It provides a daemon which
                   maintains its own "clock", schedules events,
                   provides logging, and ensures that each agent gets
                   its turn to use the CPU. You can use other
                   applications on the computer at the same time
                   without fear of interfering with experiments; they
                   will run normally, just more slowly. See the
                   tutorial at
                   <https://github.com/mhwombat/creatur-examples/raw/master/Tutorial.pdf>
                   for examples on how to use the
                   Créatúr framework.
                   .
                   About the name: \"Créatúr\" (pronounced kray-toor)
                   is an Irish word meaning animal, creature, or an
                   unfortunate person.
Category:          AI
License:           BSD3
License-file:      LICENSE
Copyright:         (c) Amy de Buitléir 2010-2015
Homepage:          https://github.com/mhwombat/creatur
Bug-reports:       https://github.com/mhwombat/creatur/issues
Author:            Amy de Buitléir
Maintainer:        amy@nualeargais.ie
Build-Type:        Simple
Cabal-Version:     >=1.8

source-repository head
  type:     git
  location: https://github.com/mhwombat/creatur.git

source-repository this
  type:     git
  location: https://github.com/mhwombat/creatur.git
  tag:      5.9.10

library
  GHC-Options:      -Wall -fno-warn-orphans
  Hs-source-dirs:   src
  exposed-modules:
                    ALife.Creatur,
                    ALife.Creatur.Checklist,
                    ALife.Creatur.Clock,
                    ALife.Creatur.Counter,
                    ALife.Creatur.Daemon,
                    ALife.Creatur.Database,
                    ALife.Creatur.Database.CachedFileSystem,
                    ALife.Creatur.Database.CachedFileSystemInternal,
                    ALife.Creatur.Database.FileSystem,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.Analysis,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCBool,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCWord8,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCWord16,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.Diploid,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.Recombination,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.Reproduction.Sexual,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.Reproduction.SimplifiedSexual,
                    ALife.Creatur.Logger,
                    ALife.Creatur.Logger.SimpleLogger,
                    ALife.Creatur.Logger.SimpleRotatingLogger,
                    ALife.Creatur.Namer,
                    ALife.Creatur.Persistent,
                    ALife.Creatur.Universe,
                    ALife.Creatur.Task,
                    ALife.Creatur.Util
  Other-modules:    Paths_creatur
  Build-Depends:
                    array ==0.5.*,
                    base ==4.* && >= 4.8,
                    bytestring ==0.10.*,
                    cond ==0.4.*,
                    cereal ==0.5.*,
                    directory ==1.2.*,
                    exceptions ==0.8.*,
                    filepath ==1.4.*,
                    gray-extended ==1.*,
                    hdaemonize ==0.5.*,
                    hsyslog ==2.0,
                    MonadRandom ==0.4.*,
                    mtl ==2.2.*,
                    old-locale ==1.0.*,
                    process ==1.4.*,
                    random ==1.1.*,
                    split ==0.2.*,
                    time ==1.6.*,
                    transformers ==0.5.*,
                    unix ==2.7.*,
                    zlib ==0.6.*

Test-suite creatur-tests
  Type:             exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Main-is:          TestAll.hs
  GHC-Options:      -Wall
  Hs-source-dirs:   test
  Build-Depends:
                    array ==0.5.*,
                    base ==4.* && >= 4.8,
                    binary ==0.7.*,
                    cereal ==0.5.*,
                    creatur,
                    directory ==1.2.*,
                    filepath ==1.4.*,
                    hsyslog ==2.0,
                    HUnit ==1.3.*,
                    MonadRandom ==0.4.*,
                    mtl ==2.2.*,
                    temporary ==1.2.*,
                    test-framework ==0.8.*,
                    test-framework-hunit ==0.3.*,
                    test-framework-quickcheck2 ==0.3.*,
                    QuickCheck ==2.8.*
  Other-modules:    ALife.Creatur.ChecklistQC
                    ALife.Creatur.CounterQC
                    ALife.Creatur.Database.CachedFileSystemQC
                    ALife.Creatur.Database.FileSystemQC
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCBoolBench
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCBoolQC
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCWord16QC
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCWord8Bench
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCWord8QC
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.DiploidQC,
                    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.RecombinationQC
                    ALife.Creatur.PersistentQC
                    ALife.Creatur.UniverseQC
                    ALife.Creatur.UtilQC


-- Benchmark creatur-bench
--   Type:             exitcode-stdio-1.0
--   Main-is:          BenchAll.hs
--   GHC-Options:      -Wall
--   Hs-source-dirs:   test
--   Build-Depends:
--                     base ==4.* && >= 4.8,
--                     creatur,
--                     criterion ==0.8.*,
--                     test-framework ==0.8.*
--   Other-modules:    ALife.Creatur.Genetics.BRGCWord8Bench
```

And here's what's in my dist-newstyle directory:

```
$ find dist-newstyle 
dist-newstyle
dist-newstyle/tmp
dist-newstyle/cache
dist-newstyle/cache/source-hashes
dist-newstyle/cache/improved-plan
dist-newstyle/cache/plan.json
dist-newstyle/cache/compiler
dist-newstyle/cache/elaborated-plan
dist-newstyle/cache/solver-plan
dist-newstyle/cache/config
dist-newstyle/packagedb
dist-newstyle/packagedb/ghc-7.10.3
dist-newstyle/packagedb/ghc-7.10.3/package.cache
dist-newstyle/packagedb/ghc-7.10.3/creatur-5.9.11-inplace.conf
dist-newstyle/build
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/cache
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/cache/registration
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/cache/build
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/cache/config
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/package.conf.inplace
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/package.conf.inplace/package.cache
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/package.conf.inplace/creatur-5.9.11-inplace.conf
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/setup-config
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/libHScreatur-5.9.11-inplace.a
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/Paths_creatur.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/Paths_creatur.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/Paths_creatur.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/Paths_creatur.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/Paths_creatur.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/libHScreatur-5.9.11-inplace_p.a
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/libHScreatur-5.9.11-inplace-ghc7.10.3.so
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/autogen
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/autogen/Paths_creatur.hs
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Persistent.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Checklist.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Daemon.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Universe.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Clock.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Task.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Util.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Util.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Diploid.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCBool.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCBool.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Analysis.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord16.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Diploid.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Analysis.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Recombination.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Diploid.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Recombination.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord8.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord16.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord16.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Analysis.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord16.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Recombination.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Recombination.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCBool.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Diploid.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord8.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord16.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/Sexual.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/Sexual.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/SimplifiedSexual.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/Sexual.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/Sexual.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/Sexual.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/Sexual.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/SimplifiedSexual.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/SimplifiedSexual.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/SimplifiedSexual.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/SimplifiedSexual.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Reproduction/SimplifiedSexual.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Diploid.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Diploid.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCBool.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Analysis.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord8.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord16.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Analysis.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord8.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord8.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Recombination.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCWord8.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Analysis.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCBool.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/Recombination.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Genetics/BRGCBool.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Universe.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Namer.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Checklist.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Persistent.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Daemon.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Util.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Universe.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Counter.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Namer.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Daemon.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Counter.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Universe.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Checklist.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Universe.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Daemon.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Clock.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Daemon.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Persistent.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Namer.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Task.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Clock.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Universe.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Counter.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Counter.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Checklist.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Counter.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Clock.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Clock.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Persistent.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Clock.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Namer.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Util.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystemInternal.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystemInternal.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystemInternal.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/FileSystem.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/FileSystem.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystemInternal.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/FileSystem.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystemInternal.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/FileSystem.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystem.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystem.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystem.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/FileSystem.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystemInternal.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystem.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystem.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/CachedFileSystem.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database/FileSystem.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Task.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Task.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Checklist.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Daemon.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Persistent.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Checklist.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Util.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Database.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Namer.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Task.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Task.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Namer.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Counter.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Persistent.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Util.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleLogger.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleRotatingLogger.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleRotatingLogger.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleLogger.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleRotatingLogger.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleRotatingLogger.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleLogger.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleLogger.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleLogger.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleRotatingLogger.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleLogger.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur/Logger/SimpleRotatingLogger.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur.dyn_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur.dyn_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur.p_o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur.p_hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur.o
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/ALife/Creatur.hi
dist-newstyle/build/creatur-5.9.11/build/Paths_creatur.dyn_o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your project and did 'cabal new-build --enable-test' and it works. I also tried using `new-configure` and it seems to work. Maybe you should just clean everything and retry.

Comment: You should have a creatur-tests directory somewhere under dist-newstyle.

Comment: FWIW, it finally worked after I removed `~/.cabal` and
`~/.ghc`, then used the old cabal(-install) executable to do `cabal update` and `cabal install cabal-install`, *and* removed `cabal.project.local`.